# Drupal site sections and end user input

Tags: drupal-7

I would like to have sections of a site so the top menu is a menu of sections such as "About Us". Then I want to have a secondary menu of pages within that section in the left sidebar. I know how to lay this out in drupal, but I want to make it easy for my end users to put the page they create into the proper section of the website. Would it be possible for me to create a taxonomy of terms that represent the 5 or 6 sections of the site and then somehow create the path to the page for the section they select in the taxonomy pull down menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [Node Hierarchy](http://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy), it has exactly that functionality

Comment: Well, that did seem like the answer, but node hierarchy doesn't work with my custom module. Whenever I enable my module, the path patterns don't work. I'm not doing anything unusual in my module. All I am doing is creating a custom block for image rotation.